# How do I create a custom permalink structure for a page template

Tags: plugins, functions, permalinks, page-template

Inside my plugin, I have a page template that I would like it to follow a specific structure.

I would like the template to always use the /%postname%/ permalink structure regardless of what the default permalink structure is set to.

So if someone's structure is set to domain.com/p=123 it will load domain.com/page-name if this template is selected.

Answer (score 2):

There are different filters available to create the custom permalinks for the posts, custom posts or pages:

- [post_type_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/) - for custom post types
- [post_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_link) - only for post_types 'post'
- [page_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/page_link/) - for pages only ( which you are looking for )

Here is the sample code based on your query:

```
public function custom_permalink_for_page_template( $url, $post ) {

      if ( is_page() && is_admin() && is_page_template( 'custom_page_template' ) {

         return str_replace( get_site_url(), untrailingslashit( get_site_url() ) . "/custom-permalink-structure", $url );

      } else {
        return $url;
      }
    }
```

You can also validate the permalink structure settings in the if condition

`get_option( 'permalink_structure' )`

Comment: None of this will work if the user has their permalink structure set to Plain.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't very clear. 
I'm wanting to know if I can set a template to use a specific permalink structure, like post name (domain.com/sample-post) even if the default permalink structure is set to the plain structure (domain.com/?p=123)